# Extend NestJS Logger (old version) - where can i set LogLevels

Tags: logging, nestjs, azure-application-insights

I create a extended logger based like the answer of Ian:
[Issue with using Azure Applications Insights sdk with NestJS logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631550/issue-with-using-azure-applications-insights-sdk-with-nestjs-logger/67989596#67989596)

NestJS old version:

```
export class MyLogger extends Logger {
```

Normally you can set the log-level for the nestjs logger:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
  logger: ['error', 'warn'],
});
```

But how can i set the LogLevels if i extend the Logger.

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
const logger = await app.resolve(MyLogger);
logger.setClient(appInsights.defaultClient);
app.useLogger(logger);
```

Answer (score 0):

- If your application uses a custom logger class that extends the built-in  `Logger`, you should update it to extend the  `ConsoleLogger`  now.

***Before:***

```js
export class MyLogger extends Logger {}
```

***Now:***

```js
export class MyLogger extends ConsoleLogger {}
```

extend the built-in `ConsoleLogger` class

```js
export class MyLogger extends ConsoleLogger
```

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule, {
  bufferLogs: true,
});
app.useLogger(app.get(MyLogger));
await app.listen(3000);
```

- [extend the logger built into NestJS and use the LogsService](https://wanago.io/2021/10/04/api-nestjs-logging-typeorm/)

Please refer [Extend built-in logger](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger#extend-built-in-logger) , [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zz-log/v/0.0.1) for more information

Comment: I need a solution for the old version. I now run the check again in addition before output first in my logger class.